# Grant execute to another user?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm using Oracle to study databases.
Now I have created tables, I have populated them, I have created procedures, triggers...now I want to create another user and grant execute on a procedure, so i write the sequence:

```
create user utente identified by utente;
grant create session to utente;
grant execute "procedure_name" to utente;
disc;
conn utente;
execute "procedure_name";
```

But Oracle says "identified procedure_name must be declared"...
that is, the user does not see the procedure and all the tables!

Comment: Aside from grants and synonyms, is the procedure actually named `"procedure_name"` or is it `procedure_name`? The double-quotes make a difference.

Comment: No, it's an example...the procedure name is another, and without double-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are the only commands you ran then the new user needs to prefix the procedure name with its owner:

```
conn utente;
execute proc_owner.procedure_name;
```

If you don't want to do that every time then that user can create a synonym, as a one-off task:

```
create synonym procedure_name for proc_owner.procedure_name;
execute procedure_name;
```

---

Or the owner could create a public synonym, and grant privileges to public, if many users are supposed to be able see it. I'd only consider doing that for some fundamental procedure or function that is really needed for everyone, which is rare; I avoid public synonyms unless really necessary, but thought I should mention them anyway.